# Change string position with python

Tags: python

I want to change the position of date. Because my excel can't detect this is a date.

Before my string is day/month/year. So I want to make it like this month/day/year. Is there a way to move the position of the string with python?

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that you have already extracted the string from excel. You may use [datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) with subsequent [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime). format descriptions are [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Answer (score 0):

Use datetime module

```
import datetime
date_str = "11/12/2014" # Assume date is 2014 Dec 11.
datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, "%d/%m/%Y").strftime("%m/%d/%Y") # result: '12/11/2014'
```